# Way to implement Maximum number of different days that an employee can work in the OptaPlanner nurse roster example in drools

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I am working on a project in OptaPlanner that is close to the nurse roster example and i am trying to find a way to implement the constraint "Maximum days that an employee can work in the scheduling period".Just to mention an employee can work more shifts per day.
Currently what i have implemented is this:

**Making the employee class a planning entity and putting an @InverseRelationShadowVariable that will hold the shiftAssignment instances that the employee got assigned to**

```
@PlanningEntity
public class ShiftAssignment extends AbstractPersistable {

protected List<ShiftAssignment> employeeAssignedToShiftAssignments;

@InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "employee")
public List<ShiftAssignment> getEmployeeAssignedToShiftAssignments() {
    return employeeAssignedToShiftAssignments;
}

}
```

**Then created a method that will get called from drools every time a shiftAssignment instance gets a new employee assigned. Here it is looping through the list that is the @InverseRelationShadowVariable and puts the different days in a list , and it checks if a shiftAssignment dayIndex is not present in the list then it adds it otherwise not, and at the end returns the size of the list which is the number of different day the employee works**

```
public static int employeeMaxDaysPerPeriod(Employee employee) {
    List<ShiftAssignment> shiftAssignments = employee.getEmployeeAssignedToShiftAssignments();
    if(shiftAssignments == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    List<Integer> shiftAssignmentsDifferentDays = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ShiftAssignment shiftAssignment : shiftAssignments) {
        int shiftDayIndex = shiftAssignment.getShiftDateDayIndex();
        if (!shiftAssignmentsDifferentDays.contains(shiftDayIndex)) {
            shiftAssignmentsDifferentDays.add(shiftDayIndex);
        }
    }
    return shiftAssignmentsCountInDays.size();
}
```

**And at the end created a rule in drools that gets fired every time an employee gets assigned to a shiftAssignment. What it does is it checks if the "differentDaysInPeriod" that the employee is assigned on are bigger then the maximum days in period that the employee can work on, and adds a constraint violation of how much days are exceeded**

```
rule "maxDaysInPeriod"
when
$shiftAssignment : ShiftAssignment(employee != null)
then
int differentDaysInPeriod = Settings.employeeMaxDaysPerPeriod($shiftAssignment.getEmployee());
int maxDaysInPeriod = $shiftAssignment.getEmployee().getMaxDaysInPeriod();
if(differentDaysInPeriod > maxDaysInPeriod)
{
scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, differentDaysInPeriod - maxDaysInPeriod);
}
end
```

**I want to find out if this implementation is good and if not then how to implement it to be something like the MinMaxConsecutiveDays constraint:**

```
rule "insertEmployeeConsecutiveAssignmentStart"
    salience 2 // Do these rules first (optional, for performance)
when
    ShiftAssignment(
        $employee : employee, employee != null,
        $dayIndex : shiftDateDayIndex,
        $shiftDate : shiftDate
    )
    // The first day has no working day before it
    not ShiftAssignment(employee == $employee, shiftDateDayIndex == ($dayIndex - 1))
then
    insertLogical(new EmployeeConsecutiveAssignmentStart($employee, $shiftDate));
end
rule "insertEmployeeConsecutiveAssignmentEnd"
    salience 2 // Do these rules first (optional, for performance)
when
    ShiftAssignment(
        $employee : employee, employee != null,
        $dayIndex : shiftDateDayIndex,
        $shiftDate : shiftDate
    )
    // The last day has no working day after it
    not ShiftAssignment(employee == $employee, shiftDateDayIndex == ($dayIndex + 1))
then
    insertLogical(new EmployeeConsecutiveAssignmentEnd($employee, $shiftDate));
end

rule "insertEmployeeWorkSequence"
    salience 1 // Do these rules first (optional, for performance)
when
    EmployeeConsecutiveAssignmentStart(
        $employee : employee,
        $firstDayIndex : shiftDateDayIndex
    )

    EmployeeConsecutiveAssignmentEnd(
        employee == $employee,
        shiftDateDayIndex >= $firstDayIndex,
        $lastDayIndex : shiftDateDayIndex
    )

    // There are no free days between the first and last day
    not EmployeeConsecutiveAssignmentEnd(
        employee == $employee,
        shiftDateDayIndex >= $firstDayIndex && < $lastDayIndex
    )
then
    insertLogical(new EmployeeWorkSequence($employee, $firstDayIndex, $lastDayIndex));
end
```